# Wiring dependencies in annotated classes based on XML configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I was recently searching for an answer to a different question about load-time-weaving and autowiring and I remember coming across something like this, but I'm not sure how to configure it. Essentially, I have class instances created outside of my control, so I need load-time weaving in order to wire my dependencies automatically as instances are created. I'd like to configure the dependencies in XML, though, as it's not able to autowire a certain `List` field.

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
@Configurable
public class RuntimeCreatedBean {

    private List<RuntimeDependency> runtimeDependencies;

    // setters omitted for brevity
}
```

XML:

```
<beans>
    <bean class="RuntimeCreatedBean">
        <property name="runtimeDependencies">
            <list>
                <bean class="RuntimeDependencyOne"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Is there a way to do this, where the bean definition is used to wire the `RuntimeCreatedBean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried exactly like that, but I believe it will work exactly as you posted it. Have you tried it?

**Edit:** Yes, I just tried it in a sample project, and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer you are looking for is in this [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

You will need to include the `spring-aspects.jar` in your classpath.  It looks like what you have should work.  If not, you may need to specify to the `@Configurable` annotation the bean name to use.

```
@Configurable("RuntimeCreatedBean")
```